# How to close/kill an app on android device using appium?

Tags: java, android, appium, kill

To kill/close app I tried `driver.close(), driver.closeApp(), driver.quit()` but the app keeps running on the background.
Should one of these commands really close the application? If so, the how? If not - could someone offer an alternative solution?

Comment: please mark an appropriate answer to this question.

Answer (score 7):

None of the method that you are calling **removes the app from background** while using appium. This is what they refer to :

```
((AppiumDriver)driver).closeApp(); // Close the app which was provided in the capabilities at session creation   

((AppiumDriver)driver).close(); // from *RemoteWebDriver.java*, used to close the current browser page  

((AppiumDriver)driver).quit(); // quits the session created between the client and the server
```

so what you could possibly try and do is :

```
((AppiumDriver)driver).resetApp(); // Reset the currently running app for this session
```

OR try a combination of these two :

```
((AppiumDriver)driver).removeApp(<package name>); // Remove the specified app from the device (uninstall)
((AppiumDriver)driver).installApp(<path to apk>); // Install an app on the mobile device
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to remove the app, because the login information is going to be lost. I want to be able to see if I'm still logged in the app, even when I close and reopen it. Does resetApp() really close and reopen the app?

Comment: @ChechyThehost : In that case you shall be using the resetApp option to close and open the app I believe.

Comment: With quit() it just keeps running on the background and I have to close it manually. Resetting the application leads to losing the login information. I want to remove it from the apps runing on the background, but don't really want to reset it.

Comment: @ChechyThehost : quit disposes the session between your device and appium server and nothing on the application end to remove it from background. Did resetApp() not resolve your concern?

Comment: @ChechyThehost If this helped, do accept it as an answer to help the future readers.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest :

- resetApp()
- closeApp()
- removeApp()

  You can refer to this link : [Java-client Appium](https://github.com/appium/java-client)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the apk installation as part of the script, you can use inbuilt appium capabiltiy which closes and removes the app. And when you trigger the script again it checks whether it exists in device and if not will install it,

```
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

To close the app sesssion use the following command:

```
driver.resetApp();
```

Answer (score 2):

also you can try a manual way like this,

```
//This code will press your android device's recent button :

$driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH);

//and click to the close button of you application:

$driver.findElement(By.id("id of the element to close app")).click();
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

1. Set your capabilities

   ```
   cap.setCapability("fullReset", false);
   cap.setCapability("noReset", true);
   ```
2. Logic

   ```
   driver.closeApp();
   Boolean b = driver.isAppInstalled("here put your app's bundle ID");
   if (b == true) {
       driver.launchApp();
   } else {
       driver.installApp(app.getAbsolutePath());
   }
   ```

Maybe you need to maneuver the code a bit as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me in Python, so I just adb shelled on to the device to reset the app cache. This removes the app from recent processes and stops it running in the background.

```
os.system('adb shell "pm clear ' + desired_caps1["appPackage"] + '"')
```

desired_caps1 is the desired capabilites within my external JSON file, and obviously "appPackage" is just the package name for the app, for eg: com.example.id

Answer (score 0):

**For nativescript-dev-appium**
version 6.1.0 [release](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-appium/blob/8744490b12d95bcd0478ba76f18a7aa60688b1f2/lib/appium-driver.ts),
driver.closeApp() and driver.launchApp() are combined, use:
`driver.restartApp()`

Answer (score 0):

To kill/terminate an app, as of Appium 1.6.0 if you use UIAutomator2 driver you can use this in Java:

`driver.terminateApp(packagename);`

where *packagename* is your app package, e.g. com.twitter.android

See http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/app/terminate-app/ for reference